# How to create table in mysql database with foreign key which is primary key of another table?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE employee_detail(
 e_id int auto_increment,
 name varchar(20) not null,
 address varchar(20) not null,
 status varchar(200) not null,
 primary key (e_id),    
);
```

This is my first table(`employee_login`)and I want e_id as a foreign key in my next table (`login`) below

```
CREATE TABLE login(
 login_id int auto_increment,
 username varchar(20) not null,
 password varchar(20) not null,
 primary key (login_id),
 e_id references employee_detail(e_id) 
);
```

Comment: please show your code so far

Comment: Did you try a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like follows :

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE shirt (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    style ENUM('t-shirt', 'polo', 'dress') NOT NULL,
    color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'white', 'black') NOT NULL,
    owner SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I hope you understand the create table code. `owner` in the `shirt` table is the foreign key referencing `id` from the `person` table

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes. You were missing e_id column in your Login Table, you can't add a foreign key without adding employee_detail's primary key column which in this case is e_id. Also you can't use password as a column name since it is a preestablished query you'll need to use something else like "pass".

```
CREATE TABLE employee_detail(
 e_id int auto_increment,
 name varchar(20) not null,
 address varchar(20) not null,
 status varchar(200) not null,
 primary key (e_id));

CREATE TABLE login(
 login_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 pass VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 e_id INT,
 FOREIGN KEY (e_id) REFERENCES employee_detail(e_id) 
 );
```